# Is it possible to search a MongoDB collection, to find documents with start and end locations close to a given start/end location?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working with MongoDB and I have a collection where I have stored an origin and destination point, both covered by a 2dSphere index.  What I am trying to do is find all documents that have origins and destinations with x distance of a given start and finish point.  Is this possible to do with the C# Mongodb driver?  Thanks.

Wade